# Не обновляется график Chart.js при изменении переменной

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, chart.js

пишу сайт на Vue с отображением некоторых данных на графике из библиотеки Chart.js
Есть таблица с данными, при нажатии на строку таблицы у меня должен передаваться индекс нажатой строки в файл для генерации графика (Chart.js), то есть из переменной **selectedRowIndex** через функцию **readTypeChart** записываться в переменную **id**

Проблема в том, что переменная **selectedRowIndex** передаётся и перезаписывает **id** (console.log(this.id) в файле Chart.js это подтверждает), есть анимация рендеринга графика, но при этом данные остаются прежними
Если же в файле Chart.js поменять *let id = 0* на *let id = 1*, то график поменяется

Файл Vue.js:

```
<script>
    import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        extends: Line,
        methods: {
            ...mapActions([
                'fetchData',
                'readTypeChart'
            ]),
            onRowClick() { // Метод нажатия на строку таблицы (на него приходит evt, row, index)
                this.selectedRowIndex = arguments[2] // Задаю переменной индекс нажатой строки
            }
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'getChartData',
                'getChartOptions'
            ])
        },
        async mounted() {
            this.readTypeChart({type: this.typeChart, selectedRowIndex: this.selectedRowIndex}) // Передаю индекс в файл Chart.js
            this.renderChart(this.getChartData, this.getChartOptions)
        },
        data () {
            return {
                typeChart: 'mounth',
                selectedRowIndex: 0 // Переменная для хранения индекса строки таблицы
            }
        },
        watch: {
            selectedRowIndex() { // Слежу за изменениями переменной индекса, если меняется то передаю новые значения и делаю рендер графика
                this.readTypeChart({type: this.typeChart, selectedRowIndex: this.selectedRowIndex})
                this.renderChart(this.getChartData, this.getChartOptions)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Файл Chart.js:

```
import JSONData from '../../assets/Statistics.json'

let id = 0 // Переменная для перезаписи

export default {
    actions: {
        readTypeChart(ctx, type) { // Получаю индекс нажатой строки через type.selectedRowIndex
            this.id = type.selectedRowIndex // Перезаписываю индекс нажатой строки
            ctx.commit('updateChart', type)
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        updateChart(state, type) {
            console.log(this.id)
            if (type.type == 'mounth') {
                state.data = state.mounthData // Перезаписываю данные для графика
            } else if (type.type == 'year') {
                state.data = state.yearData
            }
        }
    }
    state: {
        mounthData: {
            labels: [ ... ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: '...',
                    data: [ JSONData[0]['2021'][0]['05'][0]['27'][id].Unique ] // Данные для графика
                }
            ]
        }
        data: [],
        options: { ... }
    },
    getters: {
        getChartData(state) { // Возвращаю новые данные
            return state.data
        },
        getChartOptions(state) {
            return state.options
        }
    }
}
```

Пример данных JSONData:

```
[
    {
        "2021": [
            {
                "05": [
                    {
                        "27": [
                            {
                                "Name": "Забанено", // Должно отображаться при id = 0
                                "Total": 12,
                                "Unique": 3
                            },
                            {
                                "Name": "Установлено принтеров", // Должно отображаться при id = 1
                                "Total": 43,
                                "Unique": 20
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

1 скриншот - В файле Vue `selectedRowIndex = 0`, в Chart.js `let id = 0`
2 скриншот - В файле Vue `selectedRowIndex = 1`, в Chart.js `let id = 0`
3 скриншот - В файле Vue `selectedRowIndex = 0`, в Chart.js `let id = 1`
4 скриншот - В файле Vue `selectedRowIndex = 1`, в Chart.js `let id = 1`

[image: В файле Vue selectedRowIndex = 0, в Chart.js let id = 0]

[image: В файле Vue selectedRowIndex = 1, в Chart.js let id = 0]

[image: В файле Vue selectedRowIndex = 0, в Chart.js let id = 1]

[image: В файле Vue selectedRowIndex = 1, в Chart.js let id = 1]

Comment: А Вы точно уверены, что `let id = 0` в таком представлении реактивно?

Comment: согласен, непонятен сакральный смысл вынесения id за пределы state

Comment: @Дмытрык Попробовал перенести id в state перед mounthData, указав id: 0, а в data написал JSONData[0]['2021'][0]['05'][0]['27'][this.id].Unique, сайт ничего не грузит теперь

Comment: по факту, id Вам не ннужно. Просто, при наступлении события, передавайте id в мутацию и переназначайте mounthData с применением переданого id